# Jolt Transformation having null in nested objects

Tags: jolt

```
Actual Json

  {
  "hits": {
    "hits": [
      {
        "_source": {
          "customer": {
            "name": "Gnana",
            "address": {
              "AdrLine": "11 main lane",
              "zipcode": "08598"
            },
            "contact": {
              "firstcontact": "fff",
              "secondcontact": "yyyy"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Joltspec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "hits": {
        "hits": {
          "": {
            "_source": {
              "customer": {
                "name": "customers[&3].&1.name",
                "address": {
                  "AdrLine": "customers[&4].&2.&1.adrline",
                  "Country": "customers[&4].&2.&1.country"
                },
                "contact": {
                  "firstcontact": "customers[&4].&2.&1.contact1",
                  "secondcontact": "customers[&4].&2.&1.contact2"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "customers[]": {
        "": {
          "customer": null
        }
      }
    }
  }
]



  I get the desired output with the following spec.



 {
  "customers": [
    {
      "customer": {
        "name": "Gnana",
        "address": {
          "adrline": "11 main lane"
        },
        "contact": {
          "contact1": "fff",
          "contact2": "yyyy"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Scenario 2 when customer is null

```
   {
  "hits": {
    "hits": [
      {
        "_source": {
          "customer": null
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

I need output as



  {
  "customers": [
    {
      "customer": null
    }
  ]
}

I am not getting customer:null in actual transformation
  {
  "customers": []
}

scenario 2 with address as null in customer object



 {
  "hits": {
    "hits": [
      {
        "_source": {
          "customer": {
            "name": "Gnana",
            "address": null,
            "contact": {
              "firstcontact": "fff",
              "secondcontact": "yyyy"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

Here address is null and I need output as



  {
  "customers": [
    {
      "customer": {
        "name": "Gnana",
        "address": null,
        "contact": {
          "contact1": "fff",
          "contact2": "yyyy"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

but I am not getting "address": null in actual transformation

```
{
  "customers": [
    {
      "customer": {
        "name": "Gnana",
        "contact": {
          "contact1": "fff",
          "contact2": "yyyy"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How to handle when (Customer)object in Json in null as I need customer:null in my response also the Object inside the another Object is null (address in customer object) as I need {customer:{Address:null}} in Jolt transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Answered here.  Requires to two "defaulting" steps.

https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/issues/651